# BlackBerry 8900 - issues in full touch screen mode with two pushScreen()

Tags: blackberry, keyboard, virtual, touchscreen

This issue appears on BB 9800 when the device/emulator is in full touch mode (closed slider).
I don't know if the issue appears on other TS devices (I have only this device).

I have the MainScreen (MS) object (where almost entire application is working here), and some "dialogs" (D1, D2) for displaying some details, which both extend FullScreen, and I display them with `UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(this)`, and I close them with `UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);`
D1 - some details
D2 - an EditField for adding some comments

If I push only one "dialog" `MS -> D1` or `MS -> D2` all things are ok.
if I push 2 "dialogs" `MS -> D1-> D2`, if I press on virtual keyboard, there are some visual mess (like no painting areas), only the first pressed key is taken from VirtualKeyboard (into edit); if I dissmiss this D2 (with `popScreen()`), the D1 has visual issues (again, like no painting areas)...

D1:

```
public class DialogBase extends FullScreen
{
    public DialogBase()
    {
        super(new VerticalFieldManager(), Field.NON_FOCUSABLE);

        . . .
    }

    . . .

    public void open()
    {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(this);
    }

    public void closeAndExit()
    {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(this);
    }
}
```

D2 is very similar to D1 (the same constructor + open + close)

Do you have an ideea?

Thank you,

Tibi.

Comment: So, the problem appears when I push a FullScreen, then (over this pushed screen) I push the second FullScreen, ONLY with the slider closed (like a full touch screen device).

If I open the slider (I have available the phisical keyboard), the issue does not appear...

I've tried with few BB 9800 OS 6.0 versions, but the issue is pressent.

 

I've tried on a BB 9850 emulator (a full touch screen device) and the code runs ok.

 

I'm doing some elementary stuff... Where is my mistake?

Comment: In Debug mode, when the issue appears, I receive in console a lot of
"PAINTING -- NOT PAINTABLE" and
"WARNING    PopupKey show():    isVisble() false while getUiEngineInternal() is not null" messages.

Comment: If I'm extending from PopupScreen, the bug doesn't appear, but the screen is like a true dialog, woth a round border, with some padding, etc. I've tried to make the PopupScreen to look like the FullScreen, but with no result.

Which is the difference (functional) between PopupScreen and FullScreen?